# Esri base maps in api google

Tags: google-maps-api-3, arcgis, esri

I want to introduce a Esri base maps as layers in api of google. is it possible?

I need help for do it, in the web there are not enought information of this theme, howewer this is a web that is working with Arcgis technology as base maps:

http://www.mapsofall.com/arenas-38866185.htm

Thank so much,

Alfred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **arcgislink** (ArcGIS Server Link for Google Maps API V3), subproject of GMaps v3-utility-library on [github](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/archive/arcgislink).

Example of what you want [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/archive/arcgislink/src/arcgislink.js).

[ArcGISOnline Services](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/archive/arcgislink/docs/examples.html#ArcGISOnline) on arcgislink for Google Maps

Comment: Cool links. Good info.

Comment: All links are not working.

Comment: @Deep Kakkar Edited the broken links. Apparently this project was archived by the Google Maps team. But still accessible, and still working on V3.

Comment: Thanks!. Can you please help me out on this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630872/display-multiple-coordinates-on-the-arcgis-map-in-next-js  I am able to display multiple markers but how can I display pop up window or info window for each?